# Cambiar entre Android Driver y iOS Driver en una sola prueba (Appium)

Tags: android, ios, programación-móvil, test, appium

Estoy tratando de crear una sola prueba en la que pueda elegir con que driver hacerla.

Estoy usando cucumber como framework pero supongo que no es tan relevante, de igual forma dejo mis features y steps:

@test

Scenario Outline: Test app

```
When Start Test "<Platform>"
Then Do the test

Examples:
  | Platform |
  | Android  |
  | IOS      |
```

Calls to my Test.java:

```
public class Test {
  public <tipodevariable> driver;
  @When("Start Test {string}")
  public Start_test (String platform){
  if (platform.equals("Android"))
    {
        driver = new InitAndroidDriver();

    }
    else { driver = new InitIOSDriver();}
     
  }
  @When("Do the test")
  public Do_the_test{
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
  }

}
```

Pero no se que tipo de variable tiene que tomar  para que pueda aceptar tanto Android Driver como IOSDriver y que pueda acceder a toda la librería interna, estuve intentando usar AppiumDriver pero no funcionó para mi por que en el do_the_test tengo que usar el context ya que es una aplicación híbrida, y el AppiumDriver parece que no tiene ese método.

Estuve intentando con Interfaces pero no soy muy bueno en eso y no pude heredar todas las propiedades tanto de Android Driver como de IOSDriver.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjunto como lo resolví:

1. Primero cree un método que me permitiera identificar qué driver ocupar y también defini la variable a Appium driver que me hacía falta.
2. Identifiqué dentro del método las posiciones del contexto (Si era nativo o webview).
3. Castié el appium driver al driver correspondiente, si necesitaba Android (AndroidDriver).

---

```
public class Test {
  public AppiumDriver driver;
  @When("Start Test {string}")
  public Start_test (String platform){
  if (platform.equals("Android"))
    {
        driver = new InitAndroidDriver();

    }
    else { driver = new InitIOSDriver();}
     
  }
  @When("Do the test")
  public Do_the_test{
   switchContext(driver,"NATIVE_APP",platform);
   //Some test here
   switchContext(driver,"WEBVIEW",platform);
 
  }


public static void switchContext (AppiumDriver driver, String context, String platform) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        int context_position = 0;
        if (context.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {context_position = 0;} else {context_position = 1;}
        if (platform.equals("Android"))
        {
                Set<String> contextNames = ((AndroidDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
                for (String contextName : contextNames) {
                    System.out.println("Contextos disponibles Android: " + contextName);
                }
                System.out.println("Contexto seleccionado: " + contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
                ((AndroidDriver)driver).context((String) contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
        }
        else {
            Set<String> contextNames = ((IOSDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
            for (String contextName : contextNames) {
                System.out.println("Contextos disponibles IOS: " + contextName);
            }
            System.out.println("Contexto seleccionado: " + contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
            ((IOSDriver)driver).context((String) contextNames.toArray()[context_position]);
        }

    }
}
```